# Phoenix server won't restart

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm following the Programming Phoenix book and all was well until on page 44 I was asked to restart the Phoenix Server.

I killed the current server with double Ctrl + C but when I try to run mix phoenix.server again nothing happens.

I just get a blank like for ages and nothing is served on localhost:4000 anymore.

I've searched the internet and even try killing beam proccess but nothing seems to work.

The server just won't give any sign of life.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing with the good fellows of Elixir Slack channel I found the solution. It was a hanged server process.

I had to do a `ps aux|grep phoenix`, find the pid for the process and then kill it with `kill -9 <pid>` where `<pid>` was the number of the phoenix.server service that was hanging.

Comment: In my case: ps aux | grep phx